# Display huge images in React Native without losing quality

Tags: react-native, image

I've already tried to use `react-native-fast-image`, but if I try to render really long pictures it will crash and give error `Canvas: trying to draw too large bitmap`.

With regular `<Image/>` it renders without errors, but with extremely low resolution.

I thought to try using `@shopify/react-native-skia`, but I can't get it to work.

Is there any solution for that?